# Has an ectopic pregnancy's blastocyst ever been made to implant?

Tags: reproduction, embryology, pregnancy

Has an ectopic pregnancy's blastocyst ever been successfully extracted from the Fallopian tube and made to implant in the uterus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this has been done by

- Wallace, C. J. (1917) [Transplantation of ectopic pregnancy from fallopian tube in cavity of uterus](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.71242/page/n573). *Surg Gynecol Obstet* **24**, 578-579
- Shettles, L. B. (1990) Tubal embryo successfully transferred in utero. *Am J Obstet Gynecol* **163**, 2026-2027

Comment: Shettles has a questionable reputation at best, and I don't know what to say about the 1917 report. I would also note Shettles 1990 case report was of a case 10 years prior.

Answer (score 2):

Not in an independently confirmed case.

A paper was once published claiming this was performed successfully:

- Pearce JM, Manyonda IT, Chamberlain GV. [Term delivery after intrauterine relocation of an ectopic pregancy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7947511). *Br J Obs Gynaecol*. 1994; 101:716–7.

This article and several others by the same author Malcolm Pearce were found to be fraudulent and were retracted:

- Lock S. [Lessons from the Pearce affair: handling scientific fraud](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2549935/pdf/bmj00597-0005.pdf). *BMJ*. 1995; 310(6994):1547-8.

Comment: What do you mean by "independently confirmed case"? Reproducible?

Comment: @Geremia The one I referred to was an obvious case of fraud once investigated. The ones you refer to in your answer were 1) a case report 10 years after the fact by an also troubled researcher, and 2) a case report from 1917. Both from single authors claiming to have done something thought to be quite difficult, and neither with any follow-up. Though it's possible they are real, they each have little more support than a Bigfoot sighting.

Comment: I'd also add that none of these articles are cited afterwards by anything but papers discussing ethics, suggesting that they have had no impact on clinical practice.

Comment: What is that? IVF successfully implants embryos (albeit at a low rate, [<37.1%, depending on female age](https://www.advancedfertility.com/images/graphs/graph35.jpg)). Are _in vitro_ conditions better than those in the Fallopian tube?

Comment: @Geremia There's a huge difference between implanting an IVF embryo de novo into the uterus, where it belongs, versus taking one that's been growing in a fallopian tube, where it does not belong, extracting it, and then reimplanting it in the uterus long after the time it would have normally implanted. There are good reasons this is not the typical course for dealing with ectopic pregnancy.

Comment: Extracting it intact is the hardest part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91627/discussion-between-geremia-and-bryan-krause).